# Angular JS - Search form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, search

I'm sure this question has been asked several times, so I'll ask it again.  I'm building a search form using Angular and require that only a single search criteria be present (e.g. first name).  What is the best method to validate the form upon submission?

Is there a simple way to 'validate' the model?

Comment: add an ng-required attribute to the control

set a ng-disabled attribute on the submit button
ng-disabled="theForm.$invalid"

Comment: So you have multiple inputs and you want to ensure only one of them has a value? Either way, you need to add more detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements. You can either write a custom directive with a *grouping* feature *(example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/w8kZn/)* or simple use the *ng-required* directice with multiple field values.

Here's a pseudo example.

```
<form name="searchForm">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.firstName" name="firstNameF" ng-required="!(data.firstName.length || data.lastName.length)" />
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.lastName" name="lastNameF" ng-required="!(data.firstName.length || data.lastName.length)http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/w8kZn/" />
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!searchForm.$valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*(working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ahL58/10/)*